Position of THREE.Group is always (0, 0, 0) & Miscalculation in finding THREE.Group position
I'm working on a Three.js application where I'm using a THREE.Group to manage selected dominoes in my scene. However, I'm encountering an issue where the position of the THREE.Group is consistently reported as (0, 0, 0), despite adding and removing objects from it. Additionally, I've implemented a method to calculate the average position of the selected dominoes within the group, but it seems to be miscalculating the position.
Steps to reproduce:
Create domino objects in the scene.
Select one or more dominoes using the selection tool.
Check the reported position of the THREE.Group.
Compare the reported position with the actual position of the selected dominoes.
Expected behavior:
The position of the THREE.Group should accurately reflect the average position of the selected dominoes within it.
Actual behavior:
The position of the THREE.Group is consistently reported as (0, 0, 0), and the calculated average position of selected dominoes seems to be incorrect.
GithubPage : https://ka-hirithik.github.io/DominoForgeStackOverFlow/
GithubCode : https://github.com/KA-Hirithik/DominoForgeStackOverFlow

When you group elements in ThreeJS, there's no calculation involved in the bounding box of the elements.
In order to calculate the position / center of the grouped elements, you can pass it to Box3 to perform boundary box calculation, and use Box3.getCenter to compute the position / center point relatively to world.
const center = new THREE.Vector3();
new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(selectedDomino).getCenter(center);
console.log(center);


Thank You so much. It now works. But for rotation how can i do it? Does the rotation is default (0, 0, 0) in my instance or need any other methods like Box3.getCenter.

Glad to hear, please upvote and/or accept the answer if you think it helped. Thank you!

But for rotation how can i do it? Does the rotation is default (0, 0, 0) in my instance or need any other methods like Box3.getCenter.
